# How to create flexible anotation with react

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I am looking for a way to create annotations in React just like the image below [image: image gotten from https://prodi.gy/features/dependencies-relations]

for example, when `Commits` is clicked and `Apple` is clicked next, then i need to draw the arrow from `Commits` to `Apple`. An example of what i want to achieve is found [here](https://prodi.gy/features/dependencies-relations)

Comment: It depends on what kind of library are you wanna use. Is there any limitations? You could achieve something similar with https://material-ui.com/components/timeline/, but I guess, this would not be as nice as the original

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick-and-dirty way would be using material-ui (if using this library anyway), and try to make the timeline component work this way (material-ui.com/components/timeline)

But, for a really nice look and feel, I would recommend dive deeper into libraries like

- Proton (https://www.npmjs.com/package/proton-js)
- Canvasjs https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/
- Recharts https://github.com/recharts/recharts

It doesn't seem to be existing out of the box ‍♂️